# Which Piece is Which?

Tags: story

A patron at the bathhouse has dropped a chess set, and you have to pick up the pieces. All the pieces are circular tokens, with something painted on the top. The box has 5 slots for the pieces, each with a different label. These labels are: Ruler, Advisor, Wizard, Rider, and Fortress. The pieces themselves have a variety of designs, which presumably denote their type. The designs are:

- One humanoid with an eagle face, lion mane, and bull horns
- Two deer with bat-like wings instead of legs
- Two snails with nautilus bodies
- Two serpentine creatures
- One with both a snail and a serpentine creature

Assuming that these pieces and slots correspond to usual chess pieces, which piece goes in which slot?

Comment: I notice you've been posting a lot of these puzzles set at a bathhouse recently. Might I suggest posting less frequently, and spending more time on each puzzle to tighten up the rules, solve path, address possible confusions, etc.? That would probably help with reception & votes.

Comment: The labels seem more or less obvious here, however I'm really not sure how we're supposed to work out which piece is which from the designs. There's no real indication or supposed pattern, and you could probably match each piece to each type of chess piece and argue it matches somehow. It will be unlikely for someone to have the same thought process as you to be able to match the pieces the way you were looking for unless theres some sort of pattern or reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, the labels:
>
>  "Ruler" for King and "Fortress" for Rook (sometimes called a Castle by children because of its appearance in a standard Staunton pattern set) are fairly obvious, and "Rider" for Knight only slightly less so.
>
>  The other two, Queen and Bishop, are a little obscure; the problem here is that there's no really good way to decide between the two possibilities. Some variants have a piece called a "vizier"; this is from the title of a mideastern potentate's chief advisor, singular, which might allow a correspondence with the Queen in chess. Unfortunately, the word "vizier" is etymologically related to "wizard", as well. [Historically, per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_chess), the Queen was originally called Advisor, so we'll go with that, leaving Bishop to correspond with Wizard.
>
>  Ruler -> King
>  Advisor -> Queen
>  Wizard -> Bishop
>  Rider -> Knight
>  Fortress -> Rook
>
>  Next, the actual pieces:
>
>  There are two singleton pieces, the humanoid and the serpent+snail. Given that a standard chess set contains only one King and one Queen of each color, these two pieces collectively are reasonably assumed to be the King and Queen. Since one of them is marked with two symbols, both of which appear individually on two pieces, and a Queen moves like either a Rook or a Bishop, we will go with the serpent+snail as the Queen, making the humanoid the King. This also gives us the serpent and the snail separately as (collectively) the Rook and the Bishop, but we haven't decided which, yet.
>
>  That means that the deer - the symbol that's on two pieces but unlike any other symbol - is the Knight (which moves unlike any other piece on the board).
>
>  The snail's shell is for protection, which is what a fortress or castle is for; this gives us the snail as the Rook, which leaves the serpent as the Bishop.
>
>  Ruler -> King -> Humanoid
>  Advisor -> Queen -> Serpent+Snail
>  Wizard -> Bishop -> Serpent
>  Rider -> Knight -> Deer
>  Fortress -> Rook -> Snail